# Как убить дочерний процесс? (Язык С, UNIX)

Tags: c, ubuntu, unix, системное-программирование, обработка-сигналов

Сейчас в университете проходим тему сигналов (предмет: Операционные системы) и как-то слабо нам всё это объясняется. Есть готовый код программы и он делает то, что нужно.
Но только я не могу добиться двух вещей:

1. Как вывести строку printf ("SIGXFSZ wykryte!"); ?

- он её просто игнорирует и сразу выполняет команду KILL

2. Как убить дочерний процесс после выполнения программы (то есть после получения дочерним процессом сигнала SIGXFSZ или после получения главным процессом сигнала SIGUSR2) ?

proces_potomny - процесс_дочерний

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void proces_potomny(int signal){

        printf("PID = %d, ", getpid());
        psignal(signal, "\nOtrzymałem signal");
        printf("Numer sygnału: %d. \n", signal);
        if(signal == 25)
            {
            printf ("SIGXFSZ wykryte!");
            kill(getppid(), SIGUSR2);
            return;
        }
        return;
}


int main(void) {
    
    sigset_t mask_set, old_mask;
    sigfillset(&mask_set);
    sigdelset(&mask_set, SIGUSR2);
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &mask_set, &old_mask);
        
    if(fork() == 0)
    {
    sigset_t p_mask_set, p_old_mask;
    sigemptyset(&p_mask_set);
    sigprocmask(SIG_SETMASK, &p_mask_set, &p_old_mask);
    
        printf(" PID: %d, PPID: %d \n", getpid(), getppid());
        for(int i=1; i<=64; i++)
        {
            signal(i, proces_potomny);
        }
    }
    
        
    for(;;)
    pause();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 1) *"он её просто игнорирует и сразу выполняет команду KILL"* сильное заявление 2) очевидно обработать получение родительским процессом сигнала SIGUSR2

Comment: Я пробовал добавлять signal (SIGUSR2, proces_finish), но тогда мне нужно в функцию proces_finish передать PID дочернего процесса, чего я не могу сделать.

Comment: Передать PID дочернего процесса ничего не мешает.

Comment: Ну так, может, покажете как это сделать?

Comment: Перед установкой обработчика сигнала следует сохранить PID дочернего процесса в глобальную переменную.

Comment: А про слона-то мы и забыли. Спасибо, я совсем забыл про то, что можно это задекларировать за телом.

Comment: Задачу решил с использованием prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGKILL); в дочернем процессе. Мне кажется, это оптимальней, но решение с глобальной переменной тоже имеет место быть.

Comment: Стоит иметь ввиду, что `prctl` не присутствует в спецификации POSIX и не является переносимой функцией.

Comment: В требованиях задания о соответствии спецификации POSIX ничего не сказано. Но на всякий случай, сделаю два варианта. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3):

> Ну так, может, покажете как это сделать?

По исходу, что Вы представили, очень трудно понять, что же Вы хотели получить на самом деле. Например, я не понимаю, почему Вы готовите аж два *sigset_t* но **не** используете ни того ни другого в *sigaction()*. У Вас вообще **нет** вызова *sigaction()*. Кто же тогда ловит сигналы?

Азы:

Любой процесс, который собирается ловить сигналы, должен:

1. Содержать функцию-обработчик сигналов с сигнатурой

   void     (*sa_sigaction)(int, siginfo_t *, void *);
2. Подготовить маску *sigset_t sa_mask;* указывающую, какие именно сигналы он собрался ловить.
3. Выполнить системный вызов *sigaction()* для того, что бы процесс начал "слушать" данный сигнал.

Вы говорите о двух процессах - родительском и дочернем. Для создания дочернего вы используете *fork()*. Это, безусловно, правильно. Вот только используете Вы его **не** правильно. По классике это должно выглядеть как-то так:

```
pid = fork(); // Создаём КОПИЮ родительского процесса

if (pid < 0) {
    printf("Ошибка!\n");
    exit(-1);
}
else if(pid == 0) {
    printf("Мы в дочернем процессе\n");
    // Делаем что-то в двоичном процессе
    exit(0); // И завершаем его
} else {
    printf("Родитель создал дочерний процесс %d\n", pid);
    // Ожидаем завершения дочернего процесса
    waitpid(pid, &wstatus, 1);
    printf("Дочерний процесс %d завершился\n", pid);
}
```

Если же вы желаете, что бы родель и порождённый обменивались сигналами, то в обоих ветках оператора *if()* надо подготовить **свои** маски сигналов и задать **свой** обработчик этих сигналов с помощью *sigaction()*.

Это в двух словах...

*man 2 sigaction*

*man 2 waitpid*

Comment: В условии задания говорится о том, что дочерний процесс при получении SIGXFSZ должен высылать сигнал SIGUSR2 процессу главному, а процесс главный только этот сигнал должен обрабатывать. Мне не нужно, чтобы процесс совершал какие-либо действия после получения сигнала, главное, чтобы сигнал принял. Поэтому там есть только маска. Не знаю, насколько это правильно с точки зрения каких-то канонов, но нас так учат. Нравиться ли это мне? Конечно, нет.

Comment: Задачу решил с использованием prctl(PR_SET_PDEATHSIG, SIGKILL); в дочернем процессе. Мне кажется, это оптимальней, но решение с глобальной переменной тоже имеет место быть.